# Kerberos ticket lifetime

Tags: cryptography, kerberos

I was just reading up on Kerberos and realized that the lifetime of a master ticket called the TGT(ticket granting ticket) is 25 hours. Is there any particular reason behind this choice of lifetime?

Comment: according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742516.aspx the lifetime is 10 hrs. Where does it say that it is 25 ?

Comment: over here, "http://itservices.stanford.edu/service/kerberos/user_guide/how"

Comment: Judging by the fact that you've taken information from Stanford's IT services, it goes to show that, the lifetime of a ticket is dependent on where it is deployed. ~10 hours is the standard in most cases since it is the average working time in an office environment. Whereas Stanford may afford to have it 25 hrs.

Comment: @eQuiNoX__ Btw, your link is broken by the ".  https://itservices.stanford.edu/service/kerberos/user_guide/how

Answer (score 1):

The [Kerberos (v5) RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt) does not specify a lifetime but *recommends* nothing more than 25 hours life for each ticket (section 8.2) and a renewal time of max. one week. There is probably no good answer here as to why Stanford chose to break that recommendation.

Comment: Okay -- but any thoughts on why "25 hours" was chosen? Seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: No, really no idea. Long hours at Stanford? Being a university, I would guess they have actually discussed and written down somewhere why they chose 25, but finding out who did or where could be a problem.

Comment: My assumption would be that they made it just long enough that they could renew a ticket for the next day before expiry. Just a guess.